# getting lower bound for an inequality

Tags: inequality

When I was reading an article I saw an inequality of the form 
$$\big(|a|^pa-|b|^pb\big)(a-b)\geq c(p)|a-b|^{p+2},$$
which was used without proof, where $p\geq 1$ and $c(p)$ is positive constant depending on $p$. As I know if $p$ is an even positive integer, it can be proved by means of Young's inequality. I tried to use the MVT to the function $f(x)=|x|^p x$, but I didn't get it. Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about a and b?

Comment: They are real numbers.

Comment: Perhaps I should ask the authors since they say that ''it is not difficult to see that the inequality holds true.'' Because of this statement I thought that it was really ''not difficult''.

Comment: The inequality is incorrect. Try a=1, b=-1, p=2. Did you mean less than?

Comment: Be careful there is $p$ dependent constant $c(p)$.

Comment: and be sure that it is as above and used to prove some new results.

Comment: I don't understand. Both sides are positive, so of course it would be true with a small enough c(p)

Comment: @tsktsktsk For any particular $a,b$ one could clearly choose a positive $c(p)$, but one must find a positive $c(p)$ which works simultaneously for all real pairs $a \neq b.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(x)=|x|^px$ and assume without loss that $a>b$ so that $a-b=|a-b|.$ Then after division by $|a-b|^{p+2}$ we wish to get the lower bound of
$$d(p)=\frac{f(a)-f(b)}{f(a-b)}.$$
Now the graph of $f(x)$ is concave up on $[0,\infty)$ and tangent to the $x$ axis at $0$, and $f(-x)=-f(x)$. In particular $f$ is strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}.$ Now fix a value of $a-b=2t$. It seems clear from the graph that the smallest value of $f(a)-f(b)=f(b+2t)-f(b)$ occurs when $a=t,\ b=-t.$ This can be shown by looking at cases as to where $a,b$ lie (positive or negative) and some simple derivative calculations, and I can include this argument if needed. Anyway when $a=t,b=-t,a-b=2t$ we obtain $d(p)=1/2^p$, which is as desired a positive constant depending on $p$ and is the lower bound of $d(p).$

Comment: Note I corrected a perhaps confusing typo in the last line, it should be $a-b=2t$ rather than $a=b=2t$ which was the typo.